# website not opening without www but opening fine with www

Tags: c#, asp.net, hosting

our site is developed in asp.net 4.0 and hosted at Rackspace, site opening fine when we use www.OURSITE.com but when we opening without WWW , throwing below error.

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 162.250.144.215:80

please help.

Comment: Add a binding in IIS with oursite.com

Comment: @mairaj: we are using rackspace, we don't have IIS access..

Comment: I don't know about rackspace but if you can contact them you should ask them.

Comment: have your dns host record be the domain name without the www and add an alias record for www

Comment: This is just only CNAME issue. Plesae just add it on your DNS setting. It will fix your issue.